# Sooner or later my dear friend messi

Tags: grammar

As you might know Lionel Messi left FC Barcelona a few months ago.

A few months later and right now I'm discussing his departure with my friend.
My friend asks:

> Why didn't the club renew Messi's contract?

I'm like:

> They didn't have the money to do so. Messi leaving Barcelona was inevitable. Thats why he left. Beside, he is 34 and too old for a football player. **He would have to/would have had to leave sooner or later (he left a couple of mounths ago and we both know that)**

**Would have to** *or* **would have had to?** Which one is grammatically correct?

What if I said "in 2 years" instead of "sooner or later"? Should I use would have to or would have had to?

Answer (score 1):

As you were talking about a hypothetical situation that, if it had arisen, would have arisen in the past you should have used the past perfect tense "...would have had to leave...".